# How to efficiently remove duplicate rows from a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I'm dealing with a very large Data Frame and I'm using `pandas` to do the analysis.
The data frame is structured as follows

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df.head()

    Source  Target  Weight
0       0   25846       1
1       0    1916       1
2   25846       0       1
3       0    4748       1
4       0   16856       1
```

The issue is that I want to remove all the "duplicates". In the sense that if I already have a row that contains a `Source` and a `Target` I do not want this information to be repeated on another row.
For instance, rows number 0 and 2 are "duplicate" in this sense and only one of them should be retained.

A simple way to get rid of all the "duplicates" is

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df = df[~((df.Source==row.Target)&(df.Target==row.Source))]
```

However, this approach is horribly slow since my data frame has about 3 million rows. Do you think there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create two temp columns to save `minimum(df.Source, df.Target)` and `maximum(df.Source, df.Target)`, and then check duplicated rows by `duplicated()` method:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (20, 2)), columns=["Source", "Target"])

df["T1"] = np.minimum(df.Source, df.Target)
df["T2"] = np.maximum(df.Source, df.Target)

df[~df[["T1", "T2"]].duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need (as usual) to use a loop with a dataframe. Use the `Series.isin` method:

So start with this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'src': [0, 0, 25, 0, 0],
    'tgt': [25, 12, 0, 85, 363]
})

print(df)



src  tgt
0    0   25
1    0   12
2   25   0
3    0   85
4    0  363
```

Then select all of the where `src` is not in `tgt`:

```
df[~(df['src'].isin(df['tgt']) & df['tgt'].isin(df['src']))]

   src  tgt
1    0   12
3    0   85
4    0  363
```

Comment: This will remove rows that aren't really duplicates.  Consider `df = pd.DataFrame({"src": [1,2,3], "tgt": [2,3,1]})`.

Comment: @DSM I don't think the OP means "duplicate" the way most pandas power users mean it. Given the limited amount of sample data provided, this reproduces the output from the OP's code.

Comment: Yeah, I think I get that, but IIUC the OP wants to remove [2,1] if he's already seen [1,2].  The example I gave doesn't have any "duplicates" in that sense, but your code removes them all.

Comment: @DSM I think you're right -- but I'll leave this here as-is since it is still a loopless improvement over the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Source and Targets appear to be mutually exclusive (i.e. you can have one, but not both).  Why not add them together (e.g. 25846 + 0) to get the unique identifier.  You can then delete the unneeded `Target` column (reducing memory), and then drop duplicates.  In the event your weights are not the same, it will take the first one by default.

```
df.Source += df.Target
df.drop('Target', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

>>> df
   Source  Weight
0   25846       1
1    1916       1
3    4748       1
4   16856       1
```

Comment: Even if that made sense (say Source and Target are position labels, and Weight is a distance: then it wouldn't really make sense to add Source and Target), what if there are Source/Target rows of 0,2 and 1,1?  [Oh, wait, sorry -- you're assuming that doesn't happen.  I still don't think this makes sense in the OP's context, but you've explicitly ruled out that case.]

Comment: It is based on the assumption that there is only one value in a give source/target row, the other being zero.  It is true in the example above with 5 rows, but obviously depends on knowledge of how the data was encoded.  If the assumption holds, this method should be very efficient.